# i want to put a link on the image only while hover and it worked , but when i hover over the link it start lagging

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make link(.fm) appearing while hovering the image, but my code isn't working (when i hover to the link it starts to appear and dissapear fast).this is the code. I tried usind z-index but it didn't worked , also tried changing positions , but without succes. Any tips please.can you please help me by typing a working code or correcting mine?

```
.fm a{
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #5D5D5D;
    color:pink;
    padding:10px;
}
.caine1 img:hover + .fm a{
    display:block;
    z-index: 1;
}
    <div class="caine1">
  <img src="1.png" width="400" height="250"></img>
  <div class="fm">
    <a href="#" id="f1">Female</a>
</div>
</div>
```

The code is working , but it have lags while hovering the .fm link

Answer (score 1):

This is another example but using javascript.
This will help with your problem that link disappears so fast.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .wrapper {
      width: 400px;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .fm {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #5D5D5D;
    }
    
    a:link,
    a:visited,
    a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: pink;
    }
    
    .caine1.fm {
      display: block;
      height: 250px;
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    .link {
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: crimson;
      z-index: 1;
      display: block;
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    .hiddenLink {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="myImage" class="caine1">

      <img id="img" src="1.png" width="400" height="250"></img>
      <div id="link" class="hiddenLink"><a href="#" class="fm">This is my hidden link</a></div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("myImage").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      document.getElementById("link").className = "link";

    });
    document.getElementById("img").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      document.getElementById("link").className = "hiddenLink";

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using display none, and there is no transition animation on this component. Display none is binary, meaning there no way to animate this. Instead, use this:

1. To control the speed of animation, change the 1s in the transition property.
2. To change what the animation looks like, change the width, height, font-size, and opacity properties in the :hover selector

```css
.fm a{
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #5D5D5D;
    color:pink;
    padding:10px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out 
}
.caine1 img:hover + .fm a{
    display:block;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="caine1">
  <img src="1.png" width="400" height="250"></img>
  <div class="fm">
    <a href="#" id="f1">Female</a>
  </div>
</div>
```